# i'd like to give scores in matrix to visualize character social network plot in r

Tags: r

i'm trying to draw a plot about kinda characters social network in text.

you know, it shows how often and together characters appear 'by using a matrix'.

but i think i'm in a stuck of giving point at specific matrix spot(?)(row,col).

matrix is consisted of each characters list rows and cols. it's the same.

if the conditions provided that two character(if messi, ronaldo) is appeared together in a same line(or within +/-2) are correct, i'm gonna give a 1 point(+1) to the position(matrix[messi,ronaldo] spot).

i post my code and additional informations :

1.
myframe
myframe is a empty matrix, all default data is 0 and row and col are characters.

crt_k is an list about all character

```
myframe<-matrix(data=0,nrow=length(crt_k), ncol=length(crt_k))

rownames(myframe)<-crt_k

colnames(myframe)<-crt_k
```

2.
f_data
f_data is a data.frame that has two col character(chr) and line(num), characters and which line is the character appeared?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnwIL.png)

so my plan is if a character appears at line 13 and 2nd guy does at line11(13-2) to line15(13+2), i make a conclusion that both are related each other so give a point the matrix position...

my sloppy code is following the bellow:

```
for (i in 1:length(f_data[,2])){
  for (j in 1:length(f_data[,2])){
    if (f_data[,2][[i]]==f_data[,2][[j]]|(f_data[,2][[i]]+1)==f_data[,2][[j]]|
        (f_data[,2][[i]]+2)==f_data[,2][[j]]|(f_data[,2][[i]]-1)==f_data[,2][[j]]|
        (f_data[,2][[i]]-2)==f_data[,2][[j]]&f_data[,2][[i]]!="")
        for (k in 1:length(myframe[,1])){
          for (q in 1:length(myframe[1,])){
            if ((f_data[,1][i]) <- colnames(myframe)[k]&(f_data[,1][j]) == rownames(myframe)[q])
              myframe[k,q]==myframe[k,q]+1
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

but no changes in myframe matrix.

Comment: shouldn't `myframe[k,q]==myframe[k,q]+1` be `myframe[k,q] <- myframe[k,q]+1`?

Comment: oh thanks. you're right. but it doesn't work after i correct it. no changes any other suggestions?